# Connect-MgGraph while still using Connect-MsolService

Tags: azure, powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I have a few scripts that run automatically on scheduled task. The old ones use Connect-MsolService with stored credential and I want to also use Connect-MgGraph.

In my testing environment, if I already authenticated with Msol I don't have to provide the credentials again for Graph, that's why i thought if I put them one after the other one, it will run.
I can't use certificates as that would have been much easier. Is there any way you know how to make those two work together. I think it doesn't work because it has to grant permission for graph, but i dont know tbh.

Comment: I'm not sure but with both applications you ca setup a POOL.  See : https://www.craig-tolley.co.uk/2016/02/09/using-connect-msolservice-inside-an-asp-net-web-application/?force_isolation=true and https://askaresh.com/tag/powershell/?force_isolation=true

Answer (score 0):

Both `connect-Msolservice` and `connect-mggraph` can be used in the same `PowerShell` script, but as you mentioned, they both require **"separate authentication and grant permissions"**.

1. ***Connect-Msolservice:***

*Authenticating with Microsoft online service means you are authenticating with the Azure AD tenant associated with Microsoft office 365 subscription. This grants access to the azure ad users and all the relevant information.*

**Note:** Before connecting with `Msolservice`, make sure that you installed credential manager module as you need to use stored credentials commands.

```
Install-Module -Name CredentialManager
Import-Module -Name CredentialManager
```

*To check whether the [stored credential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/459844/get-storedcredential-not-recognized-even-though-it) commands in the module are properly installed, I executed below command and verified.*

```
Get-Command -Module CredentialManager
```

[image]

***verification purpose:***

Here I used [`-AsCredentialObject`](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/102n15e/getstoredcredential_all_target_properties/)  flag to return a credential object, which reveals the Target Name.

```
Get-StoredCredential -Target (Get-StoredCredential -AsCredentialObject).TargetName[0]
```

[image]

***Alternatively***, you can use target with username using below command:

```
$msolcred = get-storedcredential -Target <username>
Connect-MsolService -Credential $msolcred
```

***Connected msol service successfully:***

[image]

***Retrieved `msol` users using `get-msoluser` to check whether it is connected properly.***

[image]

2. ***Connect-Mggraph:***

*Authenticating with* `Connect-MgGraph` *means that you are authenticating with the Microsoft Graph API. You need to have an administrator role for Azure AD tenant associated with your subscription to grant permissions.*

*Example shown in below image.*

[image]

***To connect with Microsoft graph API, I tried retrieving the credentials using*** `get-credential -username xxxxxx` ***command as shown:***

[image]

***Executed*** `Connect-MgGraph` ***and it was authenticated successfully.***

[image]

**Note:** However, I would suggest not to store the credentials because it allows others to access your scripts and information. Instead, whenever credentials are required, you can use them.